# Why is this array comparison not working in Google Sheets (using Apps Script)?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I'm used to comparing arrays like this, but this is not working as expected this time:
The data compared is different, but it keeps saying it is duplicated.
[image]

Here's the code I'm using:

```
function salvarPrevVendas() {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(3000);
  if (lock.hasLock()) {
    var sourceSheet = 'PCP';
    var destinationSheet = 'PrevVendasDB';
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
    var LastRowSource = sheet.getLastRow();
    var values = sheet.getRange(40, 1, 57, 10).getValues();
    var csh = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
    var data = new Array();
    var dbData = csh.getRange(2, 1, csh.getLastRow(), 10).getValues();
    var pushedDbData = new Array();
    var date = sheet.getRange("I34").getValue();
    var vendedor = sheet.getRange("I35").getValue();

    //Loops through the range of items in the hidden columns and pushes these data into an array (data);
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] != '') {
        data.push(values[i]);
      }
    }
     
    //Loops through the DB sheet and pushes these data into an array (pushedDbData) to be compared later;
    for (var n = 0; n < dbData.length; n++) {
      //Logger.log("Valor da Data no DB: " + dbData[n][0].valueOf())
      if (dbData[n][0].valueOf() == date.valueOf() && dbData[n][1] == vendedor) {
        pushedDbData.push(dbData[n]);
      }
    }    

var duplicate = false;
    loop1:
    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
      loop2:
      for (var j = 0; j < pushedDbData.length; j++) {
        if (data[x].join() == pushedDbData[j].join()) {
          duplicate = true;
          break loop1;
        }
      }
    }
```

I have also tried a different approach, but it gives me the same result:

```
var obj = data.reduce((o, r) => Object.assign(o, { [JSON.stringify(r.join())]: true }), {});
    var duplicate = "";
    if (pushedDbData.length < 1) {
      duplicate = false
    } else {
      duplicate = pushedDbData.every(e => obj[JSON.stringify(e.join())]);
    }
```

Expected result:
duplicate = false

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It is unclear whether `data` and `pushedDbData` are simple 1D arrays or 2D arrays (the kind you get with `Range.getValues()`). Please show some example data and your expected result so that a possible solution can be properly tested.

Comment: Hi, @doubleunary! Just added some more code for reference. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For us to test your code, kindly include sample data and the desired output in your post above

Comment: Include also how variable `values` was defined.

Comment: Just added it, @NikkoJ.! This is supposed to compare the data and return false. Thank you!

Comment: @AntonioSantos - We cannot test your code unless you provide us a sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Here it is, @NikkoJ.!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R-msciqzw6A5HBvNh6UFTnVxcgQkOL8j52xXbT1KRJc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233525/discussion-between-nikko-j-and-antonio-santos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparing:

```
var duplicate = false;
    loop1:
    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
      loop2:
      for (var j = 0; j < pushedDbData.length; j++) {
        if (data[x].join() == pushedDbData[j].join()) {
          duplicate = true;
          break loop1;
        }
      }
    }
```

works just fine. Your original data has difference in column `H`. The comparing halts the loop and value `duplicate` is false.

[image]

I tried to add "1045" in `H40` and the value `duplicate` became `true`. Which is a correct result of the comparing.

[image]

But it eludes me, what should the script do? Now it works fine, as far as I can see.

**Update** (tests)

```js
// this is exactly your code

function has_duplicates(data, pushedDbData) {

    var duplicate = false;
    loop1:
    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        loop2:
        for (var j = 0; j < pushedDbData.length; j++) {
            if (data[x].join() == pushedDbData[j].join()) {
                duplicate = true;
                break loop1;
            }
        }
    }
    return duplicate
}

arr1 = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']];
arr2 = [...arr1];             // arr2 = arr1
arr3 = [...arr2, ['d']];      // "add row" ['d'] to arr2
arr4 = [['e'], ['f'], ['g']]; // arr4 != arr1
arr5 = [...arr4, ['a']];      // "add row" ['a'] to arr4
arr6 = [...arr4, ['h']];      // "add row" ['h'] to arr4

console.log(has_duplicates(arr1, arr2)); // true
console.log(has_duplicates(arr1, arr3)); // true
console.log(has_duplicates(arr1, arr4)); // false
console.log(has_duplicates(arr1, arr5)); // true
console.log(has_duplicates(arr1, arr6)); // false
```

It works.

Sorry, I don't understand what are you trying to get.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for the attention. If I happen to bring that set of data to this screen, add one more row and try to save it back, it'll say it's duplicated, although there's an additional row. That's what bugging me

Comment: I still can't get what do you want. You have two arrays. You compare them row by row. If one of the rows are identical you stop the checking and get `duplicate = true` and do something. If no identical rows was found you get `duplicate = false` and do something else. All of this works fine in your script, as far as I can tell. I suspect you want something else, but what?

Comment: The goal is to check if anything has changed within each row being compared. However, the way it is, if there is a new row added, this rows doesn't get compared. Because there is a new row, duplicate should be false, but it's giving me true.

Comment: If you add new element(s) to any of these arrays or both array the comparing will get correct results. I see no problem in the algorithm. See my update.  But as for 'add new row'... I see in your code the fixed range `(40, 1, 57, 10)` if you add a new row beyond this range it will not count.

Comment: Hi Yuri! I guess the is issue is that I am trying to compare if anything has changed within each row, let's say a price of an item existing in the data and in the pushedDbData, as well as the array as a whole. In that case, if existing rows are similar, but I got a new one added, then the duplicate will be false, since the data is equal row wise, but there's a new row added.

Comment: I'm still confused. You have two different arrays. If you add a new row to `array2` and this row contains unique new data the comparison will give you `duplicates = false`. If the new row contains exactly the same data as one of the rows in `array1` the comparison will found it and give you `duplicates = true`.

Comment: This is what ended up solving this:
var obj = pushedDbData.reduce((o, r) => Object.assign(o, {[JSON.stringify(r.join())]: true}), {});
var duplicate = data.every(e => obj[JSON.stringify(e.join())]);
Again, I don't know why this relatively easy task (compare arrays) has been tso troublesome for me. Of course, I am missing things in terms of concept... but thanks a million for helping me crunch it.